# Run a Python script on every text file in a folder

Tags: python

Is there a way to run a python script on every text file in a folder?
So for example I want to delete the first 5 lines of every text file in that folder what would I have to do?

Comment: This partially depends on how you define text file; is it just files that end a .txt, all files (but not directories), or do you need to do some more inspection to separate binary files from test files?  Also, look at os.listdir()

Comment: its just all files that end in .txt

Answer (score 3):

Simply match all the files in the directory using the glob module

```
import glob
import os
import os.path
import sys

dir_of_interest = sys.argv[1]
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_of_interest, "*.txt"))
for f in files:
    ... do stuff ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("path_to_your_dir"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        #do_simething
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate om tmarstrand's answer:

```
import glob
import os.path
import sys

dir_of_interest = sys.argv[1]
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_of_interest, "*.txt"))
for file in files:
    with open(file, "rw") as f:
         f.writelines(f.readlines()[5:])
```

Comment: After running your script I got the following error message: ~/Documents/allfolder.py:8: IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: @user3413472 try it again now, I pasted it in too hastily.